# How to find a document with Bson type in mongo in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, find-by-sql

I want to find a role details with specified username in MongoDb with Drivers in C#.
I don't want to use any builders or linq methods.

I tried this to insert a Bson document and it worked.

```
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collec = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user");

            var documnt = new BsonDocument{
                {"username", txtUsername.Text},
                {"password", txtPassword.Password}
            };
            var check_count = collec.CountDocuments(documnt);
```

But when I tried this code to find a role with username its not working:

```
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collec = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user");
            var documnt = new BsonDocument{
                {"username", "admin"},
                {"role", 1}
            };
            var role = collec.Find(documnt);
            txtTestRole.Text = role.ToString();
```

I got this as output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXdG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to materialize the query.

As you query for single record, you can use [IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.SingleOrDefault Method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions_SingleOrDefault__1.htm).

Or you can refer to [`IFindFluent` (Extension methods section)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm) to select the method that is best suited to you.

Next, from returned `BsonDocument` to select the specific field for the displayed value.

```cs
var user = collec.Find(documnt)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (user == null)
{
  // Handle user not exist
  return;
}

txtTestRole.Text = user["role"].ToString();
```